# What technologies/languages/things do I need to use to create a program that can mess with Windows?

Tags: windows

For example I once saw someone who had created a program that displays your battery percentage in your taskbar on Windows. How would I do program like this? I have no I idea where to start.

Comment: Any language that can call functions in the Win32 API can create a window that is a child of the taskbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know C, and the Windows API to write that program.

Learning C is valuable.

No one should be writing C code for anything.

Comment: except my university require us to write c and be examined on it :(

Comment: @ame There's nothing wrong with learning C. C teaches you a lot things that are relevant in *any* programming language. It's just that we shouldn't keep writing C code to solve real-world problems. With more than half of a century of data, we must have come to the obvious conclusion: We cannot write correct C code and maintain its correctness over time. That doesn't diminish the value of learning C as an exercise.